# Selenium-Webdriver and PhantomJS on Openshift/Ruby - Error: "Unable to find phantomjs executable"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, openshift, watir

I am working on a web testing project on the Openshift platform (free tier) using Selenium-webdriver, watir, PhantomJS headless browser, etc. and am encountering an error for which I can not find a solution.

Background:  I am fairly new to Ruby, Linux, web application testing, etc.  I have worked to install an Openshift (free tier) Ruby gear and have been successful on that part.  I can SFTP into the gear via Filezilla, can SSH into the App via Putty and have a Windows 10 desktop that has the OpenShift tools on it (GIT, etc.)  I have installed Selenium-Webdriver and PhantomJS.

I am trying to work through the below "Web Application Testing in Ruby" guide to implement the below code on the Openshift platform.

Guide:
https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read#leanpub-auto-irb-interactive-ruby-shell

Code I am trying to implement:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
browser.get "http://google.com"
p browser.current_url
p browser.title
browser.find_element(name: "q").send_keys "watir"
browser.find_element(name: "q").clear
p browser.find_element(name: "q").attribute(:name)
p browser.find_element(name: "q").attribute(:class)
p browser.find_element(name: "q").attribute(:type)
p browser.find_element(name: "q").
attribute(:autocomplete)
browser.save_screenshot "phantomjs.png"
p browser.page_source
p browser.find_element(name: "q").
attribute(:outerHTML)
browser.quit
```

When I run this code as instructed via the following command:
    ruby headless_phantomjs.rb

I get the following error:

```
/var/lib/openshift/MYAPPID/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.rb:39:in `executable_path': Unable to find phantomjs executable. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /var/lib/openshift/55e5f36b89f5cf105a000102/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/service.rb:47:in `default_service'
    from /var/lib/openshift/55e5f36b89f5cf105a000102/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/bridge.rb:38:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/openshift/55e5f36b89f5cf105a000102/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:64:in `new'
    from /var/lib/openshift/55e5f36b89f5cf105a000102/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:64:in `for'
    from /var/lib/openshift/55e5f36b89f5cf105a000102/.gem/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
    from headless_phantomjs.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

In IRB in Ruby I can use the Path command to find the Path:
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/  but can't get to it or edit it.

I have verified that the phantomJS executable is in the following directory under my app:
/app-root/data/phantomjs/bin

**Question:  How do I get past this error and let Selenium webdriver see path for PhantomJS?**

Help appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

When the PhantomJS executable is not in your path, you will need to use the `path=` method tell Selenium-WebDriver where to look:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = '/app-root/data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
```

Comment: Thanks for your message.  I tried this but I get the following error:  `assert_file': not a file: "/approot/data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs".  I tried both phantomjs and phantomjs.exe with no success.  Must be something related to the Openshift platform?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have experience with Openshift so I do not know how their file structure works. Have you tried giving the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by failing to find phantomjs.
So you need to install it first and add the path.

For example in Windows, test.rb

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'phantomjs'

Selenium::WebDriver::PhantomJS.path = 'C:\\Users\\name\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
puts driver.title  
driver.quit
```